# Nginx server not working with trailing slash

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, ubuntu-20.04, php-7.4

I have setup Ubuntu 20.4 with Nginx.

All working fine except following

When someone hit `https://www.example.com/webservice.php` all working fine as expected.

but If tried to hit `https://www.example.com/webservice.php/` then it gives 404 error.
here, It just have extra slash at end.

I already tried to update Nginx default file as follow with rewrite rules
`rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;`
However it redirect to `webservice.php` from `webservice.php/`

But it just result empty page while it rewriting it doesn't pass it request body there.

Please, any solution?

Comment: Use [HTTP 308](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/308) redirect for POST requests instead of HTTP 301: `if ($uri ~ ^(/.*)/) { return 308 $1; }`. If there can be some query arguments that should be preserved, use `if ($uri ~ ^(/.*)/) { return 308 $1$is_args$args; }`.

Comment: If you want `/webservice.php/` URI to be correctly processed without the redirection, it is possible to modify your PHP handler `location` block: `location ~ \.php/?$ { rewrite (^/.*)/$ $1 break; ... }`

Comment: @IvanShatsky 308 works perfectly. You are genius, Thank you very much.

Comment: @IvanShatsky 

```location ~ \.php/?$ {
    rewrite (^/.*)/$ $1 break;
  }```

is this correct way to do without redirection 308?

Comment: @IvanShatsky I want to remove 308 redirection code and want set only location. can you help me please.

Comment: Your example will overtake both `/webservice.php` and `/webservice.php/` which isn't what you need. You can use `location ~ \.php/$ { rewrite ^(.*)/$ $1 last; }`, it will search a new location after the rewrite (which will be your default PHP handler), but there is a more simple way to do it - just add `rewrite ^(.+\.php)/$ $1;` directly at the `server` block.

Answer (score 2):

By adding the slash, you are saying it's a URI pointing at a directory and not the PHP file. There is no directory called `webservice.php` I presume. Only a file. Therefore, the 404 error. Don't do that.

Comment: Rob, Application developer sometime hitting webservice.php/ and they are saying that api must be work with both with and without slash and I also agree with them.
So what is possible solution there.

This was working fine when all hosted on Apache server. It only occur issue in Nginx

Comment: @iChirag That makes no technical sense at all. A slash means "this is a directory".

Comment: @iChirag - when people refer to a url working "with or without a trailing slash", they **always** are referring to a url to a **directory**. The point is that the server should be configured correctly to open a default page in that directory (such as `index.php`, if using php pages), and that any directory reachable by a url should have such a default page. (iirc, Sometimes a redirect rule is added that observes that what is being opened is a directory, and redirects to the url with the added slash, in order to trigger that default behavior. I've seen websites behave that way.)